# Bootstrap 3 Navbar with 2 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Navbar already built for an Angular site which is using Bootstrap 4, which looks like this
[image]

I'm trying to copy this Navbar design for another website which is using Bootstrap 3.  I initially looked at seeing if i could just some CSS from the Bootstrap 4 version so it would work with version 3, but that was proving to be a headache so i just thought id start from scratch.

This is what i currently have for the Bootstrap 3 version, but im struggling to fix the column positioning.
[image]

Can anyone make a suggestion for fixing the positions of the 2 columns in the Bootstrap 3 so it looks very similar to the Bootstrap 4 version?
I also have a problem with the Collapse (mobile view nav) not working atm.

```
 <style>
        html {
            font-size: initial;
            padding: initial;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 180px;
            /* width: 100%;
            height: auto; */
        }
       

        .container-fluid {
            max-width: 1440px;
        }

        .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown > .dropdown-data-toggle:active {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .drop-nav {
            margin-top: 3px;
        }

        .fa-person {
            line-height: 0.5em !important;
        }
         
        body {
             font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
             /* line-height: 1.5; */
        }
        
        /* NEW */
        .ceda-nav-border {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e11837;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #252932;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .nav-link { 
            padding-left: 1.25rem;
            padding-right: 1.25rem;
            font-size: .875rem;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 2rem;
            color: #252932;
        }
        
        .nav-item {
            list-style-type: none;
            
        }

        .li .nav-item {
            font-size: .875rem;
            color: #000;
            line-height: 2rem;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            color:#252932;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;
        }

        .dropdown-divider {
            margin-bottom: .25rem !important;
            margin-top: .25rem !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
            /*padding: 1rem; */
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: .875rem;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover:before {
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            /* background-color: rgba(225,24,55,var(--bg-opacity)); */
            color: #e11837;
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .w-105 {
            width: 105%;
        }

.w-110 {
    width: 110%;
}

.w-120 {
    width: 120%;
}

.w-130 {
    width: 130%;
}

.w-175 {
    width: 175%;
}

.w-185 {
    width: 185%;
}
        
        
    </style>

  </head>

  <!-- body -->
  <body class="">
 
<div class="ceda-nav-border">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #fff;>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container-fluid clearfix">
        
            <!-- Brand/logo -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img class="ceda-logo" src="https://events.ceda.com.au/App_Themes/CEDA2020/ceda-logo.png" alt="CEDA Logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Large screen Navbar -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-1">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav float-none pull-right">
                        <li class="nav-item" style="background-color: #A5BB29;">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Join CEDA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign in</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav float-none pull-right">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Research and policy</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu w-120" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/research-and-policy/Current-research-focus">Current research focus</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/ResearchAndPolicies/Research">Research</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/research-and-policy/Pulse-polling-survey">Pulse polling surveys</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Membership</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">CEDA Learning</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu w-185" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning/Public-Policy-Dynamics">Public Policy Dynamics</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning/Copland-Leadership-Program">Copland Leadership Program</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Events and programs</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Upcoming events</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Past events</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/ResearchAndPolicies/Research/Economy/environmental-social-and-governance">ESG Community</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">News and resources</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/News">News</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/MediaReleases">Media release</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/Opinion">Opinion articles</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/Podcasts">Podcasts</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/MediaMentions">Media mentions</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/VideosAndPhotos">Videos and photos</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">About</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About/Our-Story">Our Story</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/About/Our-People">Our People</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About/Annual-reports">Annual Reports</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are missing a quotation mark at `<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #fff;>`. Adding it (`... #fff"`) already results in the following view:

[image: Resulting navbar after adding quotation mark]

However, the view depends on the width of the page: As soon as the width is too low, the brand breaks the layout. This is caused by both the number of items in your second navbar and your brand logo. A dirty fix for reducing this effect is defining the `height` of your logo with `1px` like `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="height: 1px;">`. The result would look like this:

[image: Image showing minimal offset between navbars]

Regarding the mobile navbar: The collapse button is not visible, even though it exists, see here:

[image: Debug view of the navbar showing the invisible collapse button]

You could add:

```
.icon-bar {
    background: black;
}
```

and it will be shown. And it works, too:

[image: Working mobile navbar]

For testing purposes, I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8chozxkj/25/). Maybe this helps to adjust the solution even further.

Good luck!

Comment: i accepted your answer :-)  i figured out about 2days after posting the question that the navbar-header class with its height was the problem, but i didn't get around to looking at icon-bar class as i decided to work on other things... so thanks.